# Client/Windows 8 Hyper-V Role Questions

Tags: discussion

I wanted to get a view of the communities opinions on questions that focus on the client Hyper-V feature in Windows 8 and if questions around it belong here or on places like SuperUser.

My own point of view is that questions that have issues with a Windows 8 host running Hyper-V would more closely resemble a Windows 8 host running VMWare Workstation/player (which normally wouldn't belong here) to that of a question on a Windows 2012 server running the Hyper-V role (which normally belongs here). Yes, I know that the Hyper-V role in Windows 8 is from a technical perspective, very different than VMWare workstation/player, but the concept in usage is fairly similar in that you have a consumer level OS running a virtualization stack to run multiple operating systems on, what will usually be, consumer level hardware.

Anyway, wanted to get thoughts on this before I decided to flag a question such as [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/504429/extremely-slow-file-transfers-to-hyper-v-vm-on-local-machine) or [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/506698/how-can-i-backup-an-hyper-v-vm-in-windows-8).

Comment: As Hyper-V is a bit more "involved" than VMWare Player or VirtualBox, I'd say "leave it be" unless the OP is hopelessly out of their depth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and flies like a duck - it's probably a duck*

If the person asking the Question is a System Admin (et al), or we can't tell that they're not, then it belongs on SF. If they're not a System Admin then it would belong on SU.

I wouldn't say that VMWare Workstation/Player questions are normally off-topics, but they're most commonly used by people who aren't system administrators - they're most commonly hobbyists and developers. The same is true of quite a few other technologies. Our scope is defined by being a Professional IT Worker charged with Administering/Operating something. The rest really flows from that.

Comment: +1 - what makes most of the VMWare Workstation questions we get here "Off Topic" is that they're an end user asking us "How do I do get `$game` running in VMWare Workstation?" or similar crap. By contrast sysadmins asking questions like "How do I manage a deployment of 1000 VMWare Workstation instances & a standard VM?" or "We're thinking about using VMWare Workstation to give our developers local test environments, what do you think of `insert design here`?" are great Server Fault questions, and we very rarely see them :-/